# Unexpected application context cache hit when testing with SpringBootTest webEnvironment MOCK and DEFINED_PORT

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

When writing Spring tests using both `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)` and `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)`, I am seeing the tests reuse the same application context.

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
class DemoApplicationTestsDefinedPort {
    @Test
    void testDefinedPort() {}
}

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
class DemoApplicationTestsMock {
    @Test
    void mockTest() {}
}
```

With `logging.level.org.springframework.test.context.cache=DEBUG`, the relevant log output:

```
...
Storing ApplicationContext [912966811] in cache under key [[WebMergedContextConfiguration@74287ea3 testClass = DemoApplicationTestsDefinedPort, ...]]
...
Retrieved ApplicationContext [912966811] from cache with key [[WebMergedContextConfiguration@4dad8ec0 testClass = DemoApplicationTestsMock, ...]]
...
```

`testDefinedPort` expects a real server to be started on the port specified by `server.port`. However, depending on the order of execution `testDefinedPort` may instead reuse the application context created by `mockTest`. Is this behaviour expected?

**Update:** Raised and identified as a bug - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/23085

Comment: I would suggest to register an issue on [the issue tracker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues) of Spring Boot. I can see why it reuses the context, but I doubt that that shold happen.

Comment: I've just raised the issue here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/23085